# Minecraft says "texturepacks" instead of "resourcepacks"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had installed a Minecraft resource pack (well, to tell the truth, 2) and it said open your .minecraft folder and then locate your "resourcepack" folder and then copy it to the folder, but instead it says "texturepacks". I wouldn't mind it, but in-game, it will not show, and then it will say "Open Resource Pack Folder" and I clicked it, but it says "Could not find folder "resourcepacks". Then it says some other words, but I am NOT uninstalling those. My friend said that renaming the folder would completely screw up Minecraft and that I should reinstall it. Is this true? And if it is, will I need to repay the $30.00 that I payed for Minecraft? I have a Windows 7 computer and am using Minecraft 1.8.

Comment: No matter what happens with your resource packs, you **WILL NOT** need to repay the money you've already paid for Minecraft. Once you've bought it, you own it for life.

Comment: renaming the folder doesn't screw up minecraft. if there is a problem, the launcher usually fixes the directory problems it self.

Comment: You don't need to buy the game again if you mess up your installation. Just redownload it and enter your password (and you can repeat this on as many computers as you want).

Answer (score 2):

> I had installed a Minecraft resource pack (well, to tell the truth, 2) and it said open your .minecraft folder and then locate your "resourcepack" folder and then copy it to the folder, but instead it says "texturepacks".

#### Are you using the right version of Minecraft?

You can change versions by selecting the "Edit Profile" button at the bottom left of the launcher.
Then, change the version from [whatever your current version is] to version 1.6.1 or higher.
If it's already set to `Use latest version`, then it's something wrong with your installation.

---

> I wouldn't mind it, but in-game, it will not show, and then it will say "Open Resource Pack Folder" and I clicked it, but it says "Could not find folder "resourcepacks".

#### Is your Minecraft installed properly?

It seems you're missing the `resourcepacks` folder.
You can make a new one by going to `%AppData%\.minecraft` and then create a new folder called `resourcepacks`.

---

> Then it says some other words, but I am NOT uninstalling those. My friend said that renaming the folder would completely screw up Minecraft and that I should reinstall it. Is this true? 
>   And if it is, will I need to repay the $30.00 that I payed for Minecraft? I have a Windows 7 computer and am using Minecraft 1.8.

#### You seriously don't know what you just did right?

Firstly, **DO NOT** touch (rename/delete) any folders in your `.minecraft` folder, unless you know what you're doing.
You can install Resource Packs (if you're playing 1.6.1 or later) in the `resourcepacks` folder.
Otherwise, place texture packs into the `texturepacks` folder (if you're playing 1.5.2 or earlier). *There should not be one if you have never played Minecraft prior to 1.6.1*.

### How do I install Texture/Resource packs?

Just drag the whole file (.zip) into the `resourcepacks` folder. **Do not** extract the comperssed .zip file.

#### It's still broken.

Just close your game and restart the launcher. It should automatically fix any errors. Launching the game will also do the same.

#### Do I have to pay to reinstall?

Like most games - No, you do not. All you need to do is delete your entire `%AppData%\.minecraft` folder (Not the entire AppData folder) with the launcher closed.
Then, open the launcher. Enter your login username and password and then let it reinstall everything.
*That is unless you pirated the game, then - Yes: You do, but that's only for the first reinstall; to get your license to play it/buy a copy.*